# What is #{variable name} in web.config .net

Tags: .net, web-config, umbraco

We have received a code from vendor and need to host on our server. The vendor is using trace listner to  log errors. They have defined following line in web.config.

```
  <source name="Indivirtual" switchValue="Error">
    <listeners>
      <remove name="Default" />
      <add name="FileLogListener" type="Indivirtual.Logging.RolloverTraceListener, Indivirtual" initializeData="#{DIR.ApplicationLogs}" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

I am not able to get what is #{DIR.ApplicationLogs} . Is it directory name or a variable defined somewhere?  Neither i am able to find this variable name anywhere else in the code. Please help

Comment: `#{DIR.ApplicationLogs}` is strictly passed to the code so its value is then transformed by the vendor code itself. "Neither i am able to find this variable name anywhere else in the code" is quite normal as digesting a big code base takes time. Ask the vendor or hire an experienced consultant please, as this is not a general .NET question.

Answer (score 1):

This value looks like a placeholder that would be transformed during an automated  build and/or deploy of the application.
We have something similar since we have various environments that we auto-deploy our code to - Development, UAT and Production.
The most common example would be database connection strings.  Connection strings generally need to change for each environment, so the app can connect to Dev UAT and Prod versions of the dB.  There are many other values that may also need to vary between environments.
We use Azure DevOps for our build and deploy requirements but there are a number of other vendors that provide similar.
Ask the providers of the code to explain more if you can